# Is there any 40mV transistor's threshold value that is available in the market?

Tags: arduino, transistors

1. Is there any 40mV transistor's  threshold value that is available in the market? 
   My UNO arduino only gives 40mV signal. That is very low. We do not want to use an op amp in order to get it high. We want to use a transistor that is applicable for this 40mV.

Also, if it is impossible to find one,

2. I am measuring the signal output from the arduino pin and I am getting 40 mV. Wasn't I supposed to get 5V essentially?

Comment: Question 2 should the main question to ask -- what do you have connected to the pin that you're getting 40mV on? Like you said, you should be getting 5V on your pins, not 40mV. Do you have a schematic or example of the code that the uC is running?

Comment: @ justinrjy Our team lost the code. According to my partner, he said that the code inputs the key word "High" or "HIGH", which should give 5 volts. Anyways, this is my schematic of my circuit (excluding the uC) http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179695/how-to-isolate-two-signals-from-each-other-if-they-use-the-same-power-source

Comment: @justinrjy I think the first question is very important. The problem might be in the arduino itself. So, instead of buying a new arduino, it is just easier to buy  a transistor.

Comment: The main issue with trying to buy a transistor that operates at 40mV (which I'm not sure if it exists, as I haven't looked), is that you're now trying to fit your circuit to work with unexpected behavior rather than fix the unexpected behavior itself. This leads to cascaded problems further down the line, which makes problems exponentially harder to solve when they appear.

Comment: But, try disconnecting everything from your Uno and simply doing a digitalWrite to any DIO pin, maybe the same one you're having issues with. Does it show 5V, or 40mV? If 40mV, try replacing the chip on the Arduino (ATMega328) and give it another go.

Comment: If your previous question was adequately answered then mark the most appropriate answer as "correct" but please don't get your team to do this or they might lose their way!

Comment: @ Andy aka In general, I am not sure why I have a difficulty to choose an answer as correct since sometimes if you have a problem (question), you want to experience as much as possible the different perspectives that can lead to "approach" such a problem. If I choose -early on- the "good" answer, I would discourage others from posting their opinions. In fact, I believe that the voting feature is enough to determine the best theoretical answer. And when I accept an answer: I accept it as the most "effective" one; the one that fits my situation.

Comment: @Andyaka Anyways, I should accept an answer once I finish from solving the problem and once I start evaluate/analyze the project

Answer (score 6):

**Your team needs to get software version control as soon as possible**. Losing your source code is unacceptable. Even if this is not a professional setting, losing the source code wastes your team's time. It doesn't matter who is at fault, it will happen again if you don't get some basic source control in place. **Git, Subversion, Mercurial, any of these are better than nothing.**

What if your Arduino Uno "blew up" and needs to be repaired or replaced? **You will need to reload the firmware into the new board.** If you suspect your board got fried, and the 5V power supply is still good, first thing to try is reloading the firmware. Sometimes that's enough to fix it if it was a disruption caused by power supply issues -- this is very possible if you're driving motors.

You don't need to mess around with trying to build a one-transistor amplifier: if your board is not driving valid logic output levels then it's defective, and trying to amplify a dead board won't get you anywhere. **If your Arduino is dead, you can repair it by replacing the Atmega328 chip. If your Arduino *isn't* dead, it can already drive 5V logic levels out.** This problem won't be solved by adding more transistors. *( unless the problem turns out to be, that the load requires more than 20mA. Then a transistor amplifier would help. )*

And FYI just now I fired up my Arduino Uno, loaded some simple firmware (see below) and I measure 5.035VDC (no load) on my HP34401A DMM. So yes, indeed, an Arduino Uno does normally drive 5V levels on its digial output pins. As I think we already knew. This should be no surprise if you've read the [Atmel ATmega328 microcontroller data sheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_complete.pdf).

For VCC=5V, **VOHmin is specified as at least 4.2V minimum, tested with 20mA output current**. So if you're measuring 40mV, one of two things is happening.

- The Arduino is trying to drive logic high output, but something is drawing much more than 20mA from the digital output pin, possibly violating the Absolute Maximum (permanent damage) rating of 40mA per pin.
- The Arduino is actually driving a logic low when you're expecting logic high.

**Since your source code is gone, it's impossible to tell for certain what your Arduino is trying to do.** But you could try disconnecting the Arudino from your motor driver, and loading this new firmware, and see if you get the same result I did:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); // INPUT | OUTPUT | INPUT_PULLUP
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH); // HIGH | LOW
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

With nothing else attached, digital pin 5 should be driven to logic high (5V). If this simple test doesn't work, your Arduino has failed.